# one read_and_decode function for different training data

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to TensorFlow, and here's what I'm trying to do: save training data from different scenarios and then read them back. The sizes of feature and output may be different for different scenarios.

The issue is when I tried to read the data back, I got an exception that looks like the following:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Name: <unknown>, Key: observation, Index: 0. Number of float values != expected. Values size: 17 but output shape: []
```

The function for saving data looks like below:

```
def save_data(obs, actions, filename):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename)
    for index in range(num_examples):
        o = obs[index].tolist()
        a = actions[index].tolist()
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(
            feature = {
                'obs' : tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=o)),
                'action': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=a)),
                'obs_size' : tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[len(o)])),
                'action_size': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[len(a)])),
              }
         ))
         writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
   writer.close()
```

The function to read the data back is as follows:

```
def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        example,
        features = {
            'obs' : tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
            'action' : tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
            'obs_size': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'action_size' : tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
        }
    )

    obs_size = tf.cast(features['observation_size'], tf.int32)
    action_size = tf.cast(features['action_size'], tf.int32)

    obs_shape = tf.pack([1, obs_size])
    action_shape = tf.pack([1, action_size])

    obs = tf.reshape(obs, obs_shape)
    action = tf.reshape(action, action_shape)
```

Comment: You seem to be writing longer lists (length 17 in this case), but when reading you've specified `tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype)`, which means it's expecting something that fits into a scalar Tensor (i.e. has a single value; `[]` as a shape mean a scalar). Seeing as you've included sizes, maybe you could use a `VarLenFeature` instead?

Comment: @AllenLavoie I actually don't quite understand how the first parameter of tf.FixedLenFeature works. So tf.FixedLenFeature([17], dtype) will work? In this case, it means that I'm expecting a 1-d tensor with 17 elements? Also if you could provide me some links that show how VarLenFeature should be used, that'd great. Thanks

Comment: Right, if all of the sequences are length 17, then [17] as the shape argument to `FixedLenFeature` will work. The [parse_example docstring](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py#L246) has a few good examples of how `VarLenFeatures` map to `SparseTensors`.